# Unable to import 'crispy_forms.helper' - Pylint

Tags: python, django, pylint, django-crispy-forms

I installed crispy using `pipenv install django-crispy-forms`

`{% load crispy_forms_tags %}` works perfectly but when i try to import crispy_forms.helper like below

```py
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit
```

its says

> Unable to import 'crispy_forms.helper' pylint(import-error)

I use Python 3.9.2, and Django 3.1.7 and crispy 1.11.1

I tried to install a fresh crispy-forms but still the same problem

Comment: have you added `crispy_forms` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py...??

Comment: That looks like the Pylint tool is unable to import the library – perhaps it isn't aware of your Pipenv setup. If the app still works, you can ignore that (or better, configure Pylint correctly).

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha yes i added crispy_forms in INSTALLED_APPS